# cache two webviews separately

Tags: ios, uiwebview, cache-control

I have two uiwebviews in my application.One as the browser webview and other as screensaver webview. I wana cache the two webview separately and clear cache for the browser webview when return to home and kept the cache of screensaver webview as it is. Is it possible and how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible BUT only under either of two conditions:

#### First way. condition: you can distinguish between the requests based on the domain they are from (easier IMO)

1. Write a custom NSURLCache subclass and set it as sharedUrlCache. In there, record all the requests that are being cached. The stock cache can only find cached responses given specific requests but you need to add a method to `clearAllCachedRequestsForDomain()` instead.

#### Second way. condition: you dont have ajax calls / embedded iframes going on

1. in your webview's delegate, implement `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` and keep an array requests so that you can later in (your cache) distinguish between the origin of a request
   => you now have 2 arrays with requests of each webview
2. when you want to clear the cache for one webview but not the other call `NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeCachedResponseForRequest` passing it the elements of the array you wanna clean!
   => you use the standard cache and only remove the requests from one webview

---

NOTE: this will work if webview1 & webview2 dont share common request data. (E.G. if all the URLs of the requests differ :D) IF the requests 'overlap' you need to use a custom `NSURLCache` subclass to keep two separate caches for the requests!
(Possible too!)

Comment: shouldStartLoadWithRequest doesn't get called for all the requests that are initiated from inside an HTML page or a JS file.